# retrieving an image from the file path in the database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using the following code

```
    echo $this->Html->image($article['Article']['image']);
```

to retrieve an image from a path in the database, but instead the browser retrieves the following

```
    <img src="/loopmatic/img/uploads%5CIMG_0567.JPG" alt="">
```

Can someone help in explaining an alternative method to use, or why i see a percentage sign in the path instead of a forward slash

Answer (score 0):

`%5C` is the '\' character urlencoded. URL's are not like file systems so you have to turn the \ in a /.

I've written [a complete file storage and image processing system](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) that deals with that as well. Check it out here or just grab the method from [the helper](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/blob/master/View/Helper/ImageHelper.php#L93).

```
public function normalizePath($path) {
    return str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
}
```